# NSAttributedStringKey giving an unresolved identifier error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm following an online tutorial to build a magazine type iOS application. I'm attempting to use NSAttributedStringKey but keep getting the error shown below. Any ideas?

This is the line of code that is causing the error:

```
let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color, NSAttributedStringKey.font: font] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
```

Comment: That's an iOS 11 API.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Also, what version of Swift/Xcode are you using?

Comment: @chrismanderson The error is "Use of undeclared type NSAttributedStringKey" Xcode version - 8.3.3. I think it has something to do with a version issue but not sure if there was a way around it etc.

Comment: Xcode9 used: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color]

Answer (score 33):

The projects are probably in different versions of Swift.

In Swift 4, **NSFontAttributeName** has been replaced with **NSAttributedStringKey.font**.

as stated here [NSFontAttributeName vs NSAttributedStringKey.font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966681/nsfontattributename-vs-nsattributedstringkey-font)

Need to confirm whether it will work on versions less than ios11

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the version of Swift. The API change is a result of changes in the OS version. The change came in iOS 11, macOS 10.13, tvOS 11.0, and watchOS 4.0.

Answer (score 20):

You are trying to use an iOS 11 API on a pre-iOS 11 version (likely iOS 10). Surprised that you found a tutorial already using beta features!

In the meantime, try this.

`let attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSFontAttributeName: font]`

and that should work.

Answer (score 7):

The code you are trying to use is a new API added in iOS 11. Since you are using Xcode 8 you are not using iOS 11. So you need to use the current (non-beta) API.

```
let attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSFontAttributeName: font]
```

Comment: Thank you! that managed to get rid of the error. However, following the tutorial I am not receiving the output displayed. I'm assuming that the tutorial is possibly not able to work with my version? Tutorial - https://www.raywenderlich.com/153591/core-text-tutorial-ios-making-magazine-app

Comment: You should find a tutorial that isn't based on the new beta and iOS 11.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.3 changes Attributed key value.

```
let strName = "Hello Stackoverflow"
let string_to_color2 = "Hello"        
let attributedString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:strName)
let range2 = (strName as NSString).range(of: string_to_color2)       
attributedString1.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red , range: range2)
lblTest.attributedText = attributedString1
```

Hello will be in red color.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the version of Swift or Xcode. The API change is a result of changes in the OS version. The change came in iOS 11, macOS 10.13, tvOS 11.0, and watchOS 4.0.

Answer (score 3):

This example works only iOS11.

```
import UIKit

class VC: UIViewController { 

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passTxt: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        usernameTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "username", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: smackPurplePlaceholder])
        emailTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "email", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: smackPurplePlaceholder])
        passTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "password", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: smackPurplePlaceholder])  
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.x**

```
 // MARK: - Deal with the empty data set
// Add title for empty dataset
func title(forEmptyDataSet _: UIScrollView!) -> NSAttributedString! {
    let str = "Welcome"
    let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline)]
    return NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attrs)
}

// Add description/subtitle on empty dataset
func description(forEmptyDataSet _: UIScrollView!) -> NSAttributedString! {
    let str = "Tap the button below to add your first grokkleglob."
    let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)]
    return NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attrs)
}

// Add your image
func image(forEmptyDataSet _: UIScrollView!) -> UIImage! {
    return UIImage(named: "MYIMAGE")
}

// Add your button
func buttonTitle(forEmptyDataSet _: UIScrollView!, for _: UIControlState) -> NSAttributedString! {
    let str = "Add Grokkleglob"
    let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.callout), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    return NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attrs)
}

// Add action for button
func emptyDataSetDidTapButton(_: UIScrollView!) {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Button tapped!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Hurray", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```