# NSFontAttributeName vs NSAttributedStringKey.font

Tags: ios, swift3

I am having some trouble with Swift code in a library I have been using for a while.
It seems related to some kind of version conflict, but I am not sure.

Here is the code:

```
let attribMsg = NSAttributedString(string: msg,
                               attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23.0)])
```

Here is the error message I get from the compiler:

```
Type 'NSAttributedStringKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'font'
    Did you mean 'zone'?  Fix(button)
```

[image]

Using this code in different project I noticed that on some of them I do not get the error message and it all compiles without any problem.

I also noticed that if I replace the above code by the following:

```
let attribMsg = NSAttributedString(string: msg,
                               attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23.0)])
```

The projects with a problem will work while the others(previously working) show this other message:

```
'NSFontAttributeName' has been renamed to 'NSAttributedStringKey.font'
```

[image]

In other words some projects work with one type of code and some others work with the other type.

Needless to say that I do not want to change the code each time I switch from one project to another.

The experiments I made changing the Deployment Target of the project do not seem to make much difference.
So comes my question: **What is the way to handle this issue?**

Comment: Are the projects using different versions of Swift? (Swift 3 vs Swift 4)

Comment: In Swift 4 the key has been renamed to `NSAttributedStringKey.font`, if swift 3 use the string key, check for the swift version in your build setting

Comment: Yep. You asked the right question. That was it, I changed from 3.2 to 4.0. It works. If it was an answer instead of a comment I would accept it! Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The projects are probably in different versions of Swift.

In Swift 4, `NSFontAttributeName` has been replaced with `NSAttributedStringKey.font`.

In Swift 5, `NSFontAttributeName` has been replaced with `NSAttributedString.Key.font`.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4.2**

`NSAttributedStringKey` renamed `NSAttributedString.Key`. However for this particular issue you need to get the raw value so the solution would be `NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue`

Take a look here for an in-depth explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46459315/2440997