# Use of unresolved identifier 'NSFontAttributeName'

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I migrated my code from swift 3.3 to 4.1
And I'm getting this error. How can i fix this ? Any advice ?

```
progressView.titleLabelAttributedText = NSAttributedString(string: MyxStrings.sharedInstance.SENDING, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: Scully.sharedInstance.APP_REGULAR_FONT_SMALL!])
```

Comment: please check this url. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641877/nsattributedstringkey-giving-an-unresolved-identifier-error

Answer (score 8):

Just use like this  `NSAttributedStringKey` is an `enum`

```
progressView.titleLabelAttributedText = NSAttributedString(string: MyxStrings.sharedInstance.SENDING, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : Scully.sharedInstance.APP_REGULAR_FONT_SMALL]?)
```

Comment: you save me! thank you i love you so much! muah!